# im trying to get the position of mouse click on canvas and fill that pixel with black. this is my current code: how can i correct it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, bulma

so here is the code, ive gottent it to log mouse position and floor it. all i now need it to do is **fill rectangle** on the position of mouse click. could someone tell me how i fix this?

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const scale = 8;
const width = 785;
const height = 585;
context.fillStyle = "black";
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

context.scale(scale, scale);
context.fillRect(50, 50, 1, 1);

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", fillc, false);

function fillc(event) {
  let canvasElem = document.querySelector("canvas");

  canvasElem.addEventListener("mousedown", getMousePosition(canvas, event));

  function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    let x = Math.floor(event.clientX - rect.left);
    let y = Math.floor(event.clientY - rect.top);
    console.log("Coordinate x: " + x, "Coordinate y: " + y);
    console.log("ok");
    context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: any comments? on how i can correct this? im new to js soo

Comment: if my answer helped you outit would be nice to get some feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const scale = 8;
const width = 785;
const height = 585;
context.fillStyle = "black";
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

context.scale(scale, scale);
context.fillRect(50, 50, 1, 1);

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", fillc, false);

function fillc(event) {
  let canvasElem = document.querySelector("canvas");

  canvasElem.addEventListener("mousedown", getMousePosition(canvas, event));

  function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    let x = Math.floor(event.clientX - rect.left) / scale;
    let y = Math.floor(event.clientY - rect.top) / scale;
    console.log("Coordinate x: " + x, "Coordinate y: " + y);
    console.log("ok");
    context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

as you defined a scale you need to divide your coordinates by your scale to match up your position :)

you can also check here: https://jsfiddle.net/pt0vxrda/

Comment: it worked, also i can remove the scale if i hard code the values right?

Comment: scale defines how many pixels are used to display a 1x1 point in the canvas. if you remove it it will just be 1x1 px ... currently its 8x8 px. You dont need to scale the context ^^

Comment: @ilimango If it worked, click the arrow on the answer so the answerer gets some reputation / credit for it, it also marks the question as answered